# hypercohomology of logarithmic de Rham complex of complement of smooth divisor in smooth variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex manifold and $D \subset V$ a smooth divisor.

**Question 1** Is $H^i(V \setminus D, \mathbb{C}) \simeq 
\mathbb{H}^i ( V, \Omega^{\bullet}_V(\log D)) $ ?

**Question 2**(Edited) Ok, 1 is true. 
Is it possible to define naturally a homomorphism $H^2(V \setminus D, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow H^1(V, \Omega_V^1 (\log D))$?

(In my case $V$ is of the form $U \setminus p $ where $U$ is a $3$-dimensional smooth Stein space and $D$ is of the form $\Delta \setminus p$ where $\Delta \subset U$ is a divosor with an isolated singularity at $p$. 
Then $H^1(V, \Omega_V^1 (\log D))$ is the set of 1st order deformations of the pair $(U, \Delta)$. Since $\Delta$ has only isolated singularities, this is finite dimensional.)

I think it is true when $V$ is compact. How about non-compact case?

Comment: Q1: yes. See Deligne Theorie de Hodge II for the proof.
Q2: I don't understand this. What maps of complexes???
Anyway, in some cases, e.g. if $V$ is compact Kahler, you can get something along the lines of what you're suggesting, but for more
complicated reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited Question 2. I realized that the map I considered is not a complex homomorphism. If you have comment for a new question, please let me know. –

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you mean $\ker d: H^1(\Omega^1_V(\log D)) \rightarrow \ldots$? Is it really $H^0$? 

And I want to ask you one more. Is Question 2 treatable if $H^2( V, \mathcal{O}_V) =0$? 

Comment: Thanks. If you have comment and time, please let me know later. 

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments which were not quite accurate.
Anyway, it looks you have what you need modulo the assumption of vanishing of $H^i(X,\mathcal{O})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1:** Sure, this is true.  Another reference (beyond what Donu pointed out) is chapter 8 of Claire Voisin's *Hodge theory of ...*.  But the point is $\Omega_X^{\bullet}(\text{log} D)$ is quasi-isomorphic to the pushforward of a resolution of $\mathbb{C}$ on $X \setminus D$.  By the way, this holds not just for smooth $D$, but also for normal crossing $D$.

**Question 2:** I don't think you have maps of complexes as you describe.  For example, why do we have the map $\Omega_V^1(\text{log} D) \to \Omega^{\bullet}_V(\text{log} D)$?  If I had a map of complexes, then the image of $d : \Omega_V^0(\text{log} D) \to \Omega_V^1(\text{log} D)$ would be zero (ie, the diagram would commute).

**EDIT:** Whoops, it looks like Donu beat me to this in the comments.

**Revised Question 2:** I don't see why this should hold in general.  However, if you write down the relevant spectral sequence, and enough terms vanish (maybe the spectral sequence degenerates), you can be ok.

**EDIT (Response to the comment below):**    No, there isn't a map in general.  Even for a projective variety and $D = 0$, we only have an $E^1$ degeneration of the spectral sequence.  This means that in some sense, $H^2(X, O_X)$, $H^1(X, \Omega_X^1)$ and $H^0(X, \Omega_X^2)$ make up ${H}^2(X, \mathbb{C})$ (there is a filtration of the latter such that these terms make up the filtration).  But we have maps:

$$H^2(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^2(X, O_X), \text{ and } H^0(X, \Omega_X^2) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{C}).$$

There isn't going to be a map to the $H^1(X, \Omega_X^1)$ term in general, unless for some reason $H^2(X, O_X) = 0$ (in the non-compact/non-Kahler setting, things get more complicated as Donu mentioned above).  Anyways, if you read a little about spectral sequences and do a couple examples from that perspective, I'm sure you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you some comments on a new question, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the revise. Actually, what I really want to know is the construction of the homomorphism. I don't mind about the direct summand question. Is that homomorphism not natural?

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I can assume $H^2(V, \mathcal{O}_V) =0$. So it's OK for me.

Comment: Great! Just notice that I need some conditions in order to use this (to know that the spectral sequence degenerates).

Comment: Moreover, I can assume that $H^1(V, \mathcal{O}_V) =0$. Then there is a map $H^2(V \setminus D, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow {\rm Gr}_F^1 H^2 \subset H^1(V, \Omega^1_V(\log D))$. $\subset$ is implied by $H^1(\mathcal{O})=0$. Do you mean such a condition? 

Comment: That seems ok then.